# Differences in Registering .Net services with generics vs typeof

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to determine if there are any functional differences between registering .Net services by supplying types vs parameters, using the following formats:

```cs
//Option 1
services.AddScoped<IServiceClass, ServiceImplmentationClass>();

//Option 2
services.AddScoped(typeof(IServiceClass), typeof(ServiceImplementationClass));
```

I have always used Option 1, but I've found a scenario where it appears I need to set up Option 2 (in order to configure a NuGet package I'm making that can use various implementation).

Superficially, it seems like either option is working, but I haven't seen any explanation for what the difference actually is between them. I've only seen code snippets and blogs saying Option 2 is available. The documentation is almost identical but different enough that I think I may be overlooking some difference between the two.

I understand the DI system and lifetime and all of that, I'm just asking specifically with  these two injection approaches and if there is one that is generally seen as a better 'default' approach.

Comment: There is no difference ... firts is calling second ... choosing between them in your case is just a choosing between readability ... second version can be used for dynamic selection of implementation (fx you have app settings where you can select implementation by name then you could load assembly get type and use it)

Comment: something like settings `{ "assembly" : "path", "class" :  "Namespace.ServiceImplementationClassXXX" }` then `services.AddScoped(typeof(IServiceClass), Assebly.Load(settings["assembly"]).GetType(settings["class"]))` (not production code! just to show when it can be useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic `AddXXX<TService, TImplementation>()` method calls provide a *type-safe* overload that actually [call into](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs#L216) the non-generic `AddXXX(Type, Type)` overloads. This means that, from a runtime perspective, the calls are identical.

Difference, though, is that the generic overloads add type safety. For instance, the following code compiles but fails at runtime:

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(string), typeof(int));
```

But the following causes a *compile-time* error:

```cs
services.AddTransient<string, int>();
```

The latter line of code causes a compile error because the `AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>()` extension method is specificed as follows:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>(
    this IServiceCollection services)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : class, TService
```

The C# `where` clauses specify that `TImplementation` must be a `TService`, which can either be accomplished using sub typing or interfacing. Besides, in this case `int` is used as `TImplementation`, but `TImplementation` must be a class, while `int` is a struct. Two reasons why that line of code does not compile.

While it makes little sense trying to register string or int like this in your DI Container, it tries to demonstrate the difference in compile time behavior. A more-likely scenario is that you have a class that implemented some interface before, but you removed the interface. When you used the non-generic overloads, the code would still compile.

Not in all situations, though, the generic overloads are suitable. In some cases the types you want to register are unknown at compile time, or you need a more dynamic approach in registering types. This is typically done using Reflection where you iterate the types in your application and use a Convention over Configuration approach to register those types. This is often required in keeping the startup part of your application maintainable when working on bigger applications. This method is called Auto-Registration. The following code example demonstrates this concept of Auto-Registration:

```cs
var handlersRegistrations =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    from service in type.GetInterfaces()
    where service.IsGenericType
    where service.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
    select (service, type);
    
foreach (var reg in handlersRegistrations)
{
    services.AddTransient(reg.service, reg.type);
}
```

In this case a LINQ query is used to query the type system to find all implementations of a generic `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface. After that, the collection is iterated and all handler implementations are registered by their closed-generic `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface(s).